# HEAD is detached in repository

Tags: git, netbeans

Estou utilizando o NETBEANS e o GIT. Eu fiz algumas alterações a agora na hora de o commit esta dando essa mensagem:

> HEAD is detached in repository

O meu repositório esta desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso significa que você não está mais em um *branch* local (isso é, voltou para um commit anterior ou está explorando um commit remoto).

Para voltar ao normal (considerando que não existam novas mudanças a serem commitadas), basta fazer checkout do *branch* com o qual você quer trabalhar. Por exemplo:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 9):

Isso aconteceu porque você fez um checkout em um commit.
Provavelmente você deve ter executado esse comando `git checkout a83c7867c2`.

O git possui um cara chamado HEAD. O HEAD aponta para a atual branch. É através do HEAD que sabemos em qual branch estamos trabalhando. O comportamento normal é o HEAD sempre estar apontando para alguma branch e a branch aponta para o último commit. Ao fazer um checkout diretamente em um commit, o HEAD irá apontar diretamente para um commit. Essa situação caracteriza um detached HEAD.

A solução do Anthony Accioly resolve o seu problema.

```
git checkout master
```

Porém, se você fez algum commit no HEAD, e é o que parece, seus commits ficarão em um galho separado. Eles não vão aparecer no master. A solução para isso seria criar um branch que aponte para o último desses commits e depois fazer um merge com o master. A sequência de comandos seria:

1. `git checkout -b outra-branch` (criando um nova branch que aponta para o commit que o HEAD está apontando)
2. `git checkout master` (voltando para a branch master)
3. `git merge --no-ff outra-branch` (trazendo as alterações da outra branch para o master)
4. `git branch -d outra-branch` (se a branch não for mais necessária, pode ser removida)

Se você não quiser perder os commits feitos em um detached HEAD, você deve criar uma branch que aponte para eles. Se for executado um checkout em alguma branch, e esses commits ficarem soltos, em algum momento, o garbage collection do git irá removê-los.

Comment: bem explicativo!